# Processing bitmap files dynamically from folder using c#

Tags: c#

Camera will capture image and store in a folder(.bmp file).Simultaneously our application needs to get one by one image file from the folder for processing.(captured images will update the folder dynamically.If we use FileSystemWatcher , it may cause problem for us.(We are selecting the directory before processing of the image,so updated images will not process.Is there any solution for this problem)how to get one by one image from the folder at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) but you need to be aware of a few quirks. The watcher will raise a *Created* event when a file is first created and one or more *Modified* events as data is written to the files. There is no Close event so you can't know when the camera has stopped writing to the file.
As long as the file is open for writing, you won't be able to read it for processing and any attempt to read it will raise an exception

There are several ways you can handle this:

- You can log all events in a list and periodically process all files in the list. If you fail to open a file, just leave it in the list to process in the next processing round.
- You can delay reading the file hoping that the camera will finish writing by the time you try to read the file. If you still receive an exception, wait for a while and then retry.
- You can keep track of the Created and Modified events eg. in a dictionary keyed by the file name and try to  open the file only if no event is received for a file after a specific timeout.

Polling and timeouts can be implemented using timers.

If you don't like the delay introduced by polling, you can use a separate thread to wait on the list of events and process new events as they appear. You can use the functionality of the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) in C# 4 to do this in a relatively simple way.

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to get notified when a new file is put into the folder. Then, process the file(s).

To get the file names of all BMP files in a folder you can use:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("<path>", "*.bmp");
```

Then you can load the bitmaps normally.

Comment: captured images will update the folder dynamically.if we use  FileSystemWatcher , it may cause problem for us.(We are selecting the directory before processing of the image,so updated images will not process.is there any solution for this problem

Comment: The `FileSystemWatcher` can also handle updating of files, not only file creation. Another way would be to list the contents of the directory and store the last write time for each file. Then, periodically, iterate over all the files again, looking for new files or newer modification time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any image development will require to know how to load an image in C#.

**FromFile**

There are two direct ways to read an image file and load it into either a Bitmap or Image. Behold the C# code:

```
Image myImg = Image.FromFile("path here");
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.FromFile("path here");
```

Alternatively a Bitmap object can also be loaded with:

```
Bitmap myBmp = new Bitmap("path here");
```

The code above does not work with Image objects though, so it is best to stick with FromFile.

**Dialog Box**

Finally, to write an application that loads an image from a file, your C# program needs a dialogbox to select files. Using the .Net OpenFileDialog is simple enough. Just apply the image-loading code to the Filename chosen by the user, so for example:

```
Bitmap loadedBitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog1.Filename);
```

Of course, you don't have to necessarily load an image from a file in this manner, but it is a useful thing to know.

For more information [HERE](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-from-file.php)